# Can I forbid method to cache passed argument?

Tags: c#, pooling

Is there a way to prevent method from storing passed argument? I stumbled across this question while considering object pooling.

Let's consider given situation:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private BigObject myBigObject;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myBigObject = BigObjectsPool.Borrow();
        //initialize myBigObject with some data
    }

    public void ActUpon(ClientClass clientClassInstance)
    {
        clientClassInstance.DoStuff(myBigObject);
    }

    public void Terminate() //MyClass object is no longer needed
    {
        BigObjectsPool.Return(myBigObject);
    }
}

public abstract class ClientClass
{
    public abstract void DoStuff(BigObject bigObject);
}

public class PotentiallyDangerousClientClass : ClientClass
{
    private BigObject cachedBigObject;
    private string cachedString

    public override void DoStuff(BigObject bigObject)
    {
        cachedString = bigObject.SomeString; //this is ok
        cachedBigObject = bigObject; //this will cause problems
    }
}
```

As you can see, storing bigObject in DoStuff method is dangerous, because in future
another instance of MyClass can borrow the same BigObject instance and change it without PotentiallyDangerousClientClass knowledge. Is there a way to ensure safety when passing pooled objects as arguments?

Obvious soultion would be to never expose pooled object and use it only for internal class logic, or expose only it's immutable fields, but it heavily reduces pooling usefulness. Exposing copy of BigObject would render whole pooling obsolete, because I would no longer benefit from reduced allocation.

Comment: Why not expose only an interface where all properties are get only, allowing only your class access to the private inner class implementing `IBigObject`?

Comment: What kind of usefulness?

Comment: Don't pass an object you don't want potentially dangerous clients to have access to. As soon as the client has it, it's out of your hands. If you only want a string to be visible, only make that getter access public.

Comment: @ZoharPeled An interface changes nothing.  You still have a reference to the object and can access those members after the object has been returned from the pool.  The issue is not about restricting which members can be access, but *when* they can be accessed.

Comment: @Servy I see your point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a thin wrapper around the object that exposes it's members, but only until you release it:

```
public class TempBigObject : IDisposable
{
    private BigObject bigObject;
    public TempBigObject(BigObject bigObject)
    {
        this.bigObject = bigObject;
    }

    public string SomeString => bigObject.SomeString;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        bigObject = null;
    }
}
```

If you want to, you can change all of the members, such as `SomeString`, to throw some more meaningful exception (such as an object disposed exception) when used after disposal, rather than letting null reference exceptions happen.

You can then change `ActUpon` to something like:

```
public void ActUpon(ClientClass clientClassInstance)
{
    using TempBigObject temp = new TempBigObject(myBigObject);
    clientClassInstance.DoStuff(temp);
}
```

This would of course require the clients to use the wrapper type and not the actual type.

Comment: I really like this idea. I could also make TempBigObject a struct to completely avoid heap allocation. Thank you, this is nice solution.

Comment: @PrzemekNowaczyk No, you cannot make such a change.  If you did, then changes to the instance passed as a parameter would be unaffected by the disposal by the caller.  At that point it would be no different than if you just passed the object and didn't use a wrapper in the first place.  As usual, mutable structs are evil.

Comment: I didn't thought about that, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Pooling is a performance optimization. And as most optimizations it has an impact on the readability and maintainability of the code. It is up to you to ensure that all references have been released once you return the object to the pool. You are voluntary accepting this responsibility in pursuit of better performance.

You should probably try to limit the scope where `BigObject` is used. The fewer classes that are involved the less the chance for mistakes and failures are. In some cases it might be useful to create a wrapper for `BigObject` what can check if the wrapped object have been returned or not, and can throw an error if someone tries to use it after it has been returned.

Of course, you do not have to use pooling. In some cases regular memory allocation is fast enough, and will be safer. There are also some options that can be used to prevent or mitigate the effects of arguments being copied but are not relevant when using an object pool. A [ref struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct) can prevent the type from being used as a field of a non ref struct. Immutable objects are inherently safe to copy (Immutable in the most strict sense, i.e. "deep immutability").

Comment: _"Immutable objects are inherently safe to copy."_ - but if an object is immutable you don't need to copy it: everyone can share a singleton reference.

Comment: @Dai It is perhaps a bit sloppily formulated. But you will be copying *something*, either a reference or a value. The nice thing with immutability is that it just don't matter much.

Comment: Whether the object is immutable or not, the whole concept of a pool is that it's not safe to access the object once you've returned it.  Generally it's because the object is mutated when it's re-used, but in the unusual event that an immutable resource is able to be pooled, the mere fact it's used in a pool means it's cannot continue to be used by others.  So your second point is, at best, a way of implementing the third, because you're suggesting this thing not be pooled and that multiple logical consumers be allowed to safely access it concurrently.

Comment: @Servy I'm using "Immutability" in the most strict sense here. And if the object is immutable in that way it will not matter if it has been returned or not. It *can* be used concurrently by however many consumers. Ofc, pooling such immutable objects make little sense. That is why I mention that is is more for completeness than anything useful in a pooling scenario.

Comment: @JonasH The fact that the object is being pooled means it almost certainly isn't immutable, and probably couldn't easily be made to be so.  It doesn't make sense to pool almost any immutable object.  In the rare case the object is immutable but still pooled *the fact that it's pooled means that the object should not be accessed once it's been returned*.  That it's immutable just means that it's not going to get torn or result in otherwise impossible exceptions due to inappropriate usage, but it doesn't mean it's appropriate as per the business logic.

Comment: @Servy, All of these points are under the paragraph **"not relevant in a pooling scenario"**. Is this in any way unclear?  I thought these points might be useful to include for anyone concerned with the more general question "Can I forbid method to cache passed argument?", that are not specifically related to pooling.

Comment: It's super unclear.  If the whole section is about not using pooling then why is one option "don't use pooling", if that's already *the whole section.  If they're all about not using pooling then it's just redundant.  How is a ref struct useful to bring up if pooling isn't involved.  As you mention, they couldn't store it as a field, but if it's not pooled *you don't need to prevent storing it in a field*.  If these are entirely unrelated to the question in any way then they shouldn't really be in an answer.

Comment: @Servy I thought this would be useful to include because many more will read the title than the body of a question. A "ref struct" is *specifically* designed to prevent a method from "caching a passed argument", so I think it at least is worth mentioning. If the title was "How to prevent a pooled object from being used after it has been returned" I would agree with you.